# How to upload m4a file to server using POST in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-post

I am trying to upload file to server using post method.It is a recorded file.I am unable to do that,Here is my code.

```
 NSString *name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"18Sep15_032456PM.m4a"];

NSString *bodyString1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Id=%d&type=%d&audio=%@",39,1,name];
//Entity_Id,charms_type,charm_audio
NSData *data1 = [bodyString1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSString *strURL =@" "; // my server address

// NSData *file1Data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[recordedTmpFile path]];

// recordedTmpFile= your audio file path


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"----------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",name]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data1]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
NSLog(@"Return String= %@",returnString);
```

Please help me regarding my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use [STHTTPRequest](https://github.com/nst/STHTTPRequest). Just 2 file to include in your project and easy to use.

Example :

```
STHTTPRequest *request = [STHTTPRequest requestWithURLString:@"urlHere"];
//Any parameter for request set here
NSString *strFileName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"18Sep15_032456PM.m4a"];
request.POSTDictionary = @{ @"Id":@"39", @"type":"1"};

//upload file
NSData *filedata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePathHere];
[request addDataToUpload:filedata parameterName:@"audio" mimeType:@"audio/mp4 m4a" fileName:strFileName];
//upload block here
request.uploadProgressBlock= ^(NSInteger bytesWritten,
                        NSInteger totalBytesWritten,
                        NSInteger totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
   // notify user of upload progress
   // use the stream
}

//on completion
request.completionBlock = ^(NSDictionary *headers, NSString *body) {
   NSLog(@"headers : %@\nBody : %@",headers,body);
};

//error block here
request.errorBlock = ^(NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Error: %d", [error localizedDescription]);
};

//start request
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: but i should give 2 parameters like id and type.
NSString *bodyString1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Id=%d&type=%d&audio=%@",39,1,name];


Where shouls i give that??
And what is the filedata means?

Can I give data1 value to that?

Comment: Its a post method write.I should give id,type and audio to that where should I give in your example.

Comment: filedata, parameterNameHere what values should i give??

Comment: I am trying to that.

NSData *data1 = [strFileName dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 
    [request addDataToUpload:data1 parameterName:@"audio" mimeType:@"audio/mp4 m4a" fileName:@"strFileName"];

I add two lines like this is that correct.Please check and let me know.Thank you very much for your support till now

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'a completion block is mandatory'


I am getting this error.

Comment: I changed as you modified.but app getting terminated with above error